# Angular 7, different instances of service in different modules?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-services

In angular 7 app, I have service (test.service) with decorator `@Injectable()` **(without providedIn)** and it isn't provided in app.module, also I have 2 different modules: `client.module` and `core.module`. When I add `test.service` in both module's providers and then inject `test.service` in the client's component and in core's component I get 1 instance of `test.service`, but I expected 2.

Question 1: why does that happen?

Question 2: How can I have different instances of service in different modules?

test service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  public bla = 1

  constructor() {
    console.log('Created')
  }

}
```

client module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ClientComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [TestService]
})
```

core module:

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        coreComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule
      ],
      providers: [TestService]
    })
```

Client Component:

```
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private ts: TestService) {}

}
```

Core Component:

```
export class ClientComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private ts: TestService)
}
```

Comment: is your service also provided in your AppModule ?

Comment: No, also I edited the question to mention that

Comment: I don't be really sure but I think Angular provides services only when the active component has reference to them or when the module active has reference to the service. In your example CoreComponent has no reference to TestService in ClientModule, so when you enter to CoreComponent the TestService in ClientModule is not provided by the framework.